# Get position of ImageView relative to screen programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to get the position of my `ImageView` programmatically. By position, I mean the distance in pixel from top of the screen to that `ImageView.` I have tried every other solution posted in stackoverflow but it's not working for me. My minimum API level is 8.

These are the codes I have tried-

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
1) image.getTop();

2) private int getRelativeTop(View myView) {
    if (myView.getParent() == myView.getRootView())
        return myView.getTop();
    else
        return myView.getTop() + getRelativeTop((View) myView.getParent());
}

3) image.getLocationOnScreen(int[] locaiton);
```

Comment: Could you add some code of what you have tried?

Comment: @Carnal I have added the codes.

Comment: Great, are you using these methods onCreate?

Comment: @Carnal Yes, I am using these inside onCreate().

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to wait for the callback when the layout has been placed with children views. This is the listener you need to add to your root view in order to calculate the coordinates for your image. Otherwise it will return 0.

```
getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

        int[] locations = new int[2];
        image.getLocationOnScreen(locations);
        int x = locations[0];
        int y = locations[1];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`View.getLocationOnScreen()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen%28int%5B%5D%29) or [`getLocationInWindow()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationInWindow%28int%5B%5D%29) **BUT ONLY** after the view has been layout. `getTop()`, `getLeft()`, `getBottom()` and `getRight()` return the position relative to its parent.

Comment: I have used these. They all return 0. I don't know why.

Comment: you shouldn't call these method in onCreate(), try onWindowFocusChanged()

Answer (score -1):

```
Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                .apply(requestOptions)
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.img_place_holder)
                .apply(new RequestOptions().override(myImage.getMeasuredWidth(), myImage.getMeasuredHeight()))
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap,
                                                Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {

//                        TouchImageView   myImage1 = findViewById(R.id.image_zoom_poll_card);
                        img_zoomIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        myImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        getBitmapPositionInsideImageView(myImage, img_zoomIn);

                    }
                });
```