# Set position of view not based on its parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a situation where so far I have not been able to find an answer. I'm working on an app that uses a `PopupWindow` in two different fragments. Each of the two fragments uses two popupwindows. So there are 4 popupwindows total. There is one view that is used for all the popupwindows. That view has an up pointing arrow that needs to point at the button that was clicked to open the popupwindow, no matter where the button may be. I have tried some different combinations of `getLocationOnScreen()`, `getX()`, `getLeft()`, `setX()` and `setY()`. It is my understanding that `getLocationInWindow()` is the only one that deals with the location of a view based on the devices screen size. The other 4 all get and set values based on the view's parent. Since the button that was clicked to open the popupwindow and the view used to show the contents in the popupwindow have different parents, getX()`,`getLeft()`,`setX()`and`setY()` have resulted in setting the arrow's location at a different position for each button.

What I need, but have yet to find, is a way to set the position arrow image in the popupwindow based on the x and y coordinates I get from `getLocationOnScreen()`. But there is no `setLocationOnScreen()`.

So I need a way to calculate the arrow's position so that it sets under the button clicked, no matter where the button is or what the button's parents are. I'm sure there is a way to calculate it, I'm just not sure how.

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both getLocationOnScreen() & getLocationInWindow() are almost same, except that getLocationOnScreen() returns the coordinates relative to the whole screen while getLocationInWindow() will return the coordinates relative to the activity.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17673679)

You are not getting the proper coordinates, even though your are using correct methods. Probably, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19497699/254567) should resolve your query.

Comment: Getting the position isn't the problem. getLocationOnScreen() seems to be returning the correct numbers. I need a way to use those numbers to calculate the position of an imageview in a different layout, when both layout are being shown at the same time

Comment: @JasonCrosby I have the same problem